# Ansible Keepass integration via python script

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, keepass

i am very new to ansible and would like to test a few things.
I have a couple of Amazon EC2 instances and would like to install different software components on them. I don't want to have the (plaintext) credentials of the technical users inside of ansible scripts or config files. I know that it is possible to encrypt those files, but I want to try keepass for a central password management tool. So my installation scripts should read the credentials from a .kdbx (Keepass 2) database file before starting the actual installation.

Till now i wrote a basic python script for reading the .kdbx file. The script outputs a json object via:

```
print json.dumps(inventory, sort_keys=False)
```

The ouput looks like the following:

```
{"cdc": 
    {"cdc_test_server": 
        {"cdc_test_user": 
            {"username": "cdc_test_user", 
             "password": "password"}
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to achieve, that the python script is executed by ansible and the key value pairs of the output are included/registered as ansible variables. So far my playbook looks as follows:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: "Test Playboook Functionality"
    command: python /usr/local/test.py
    register: pass

  - debug: var=pass.stdout

  - name: "Include json user output"
    set_fact: passwords="{{pass.stdout | from_json}}"

  - debug: " {{passwords.cdc.cdc_test_server.cdc_test_user.password}} "
```

The first debug generates the correct json output, but i am not able to include the variables in ansible, so that I can use them via jinja2 notation. set_fact doesn't throw an exception, but the last debug just returns a "Hello world" - message? So my question is: How do I properly include the json key value pairs as ansible variables via task?

Comment: add `msg:` to your last debug statement: `- debug: msg="{{pass....}}"`

Comment: oh, thank you. Do you know if my approach is the preferred way for the registration of variables, or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [facts.d](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) and place your python script there to be available as a fact.
Or write a simple action plugin that returns json object to eliminate the need in stdout->from_json conversion.

Comment: The [link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) is no more available.

Answer (score 3):

See [Ansible KeePass Lookup Plugin](https://github.com/viczem/ansible-keepass)

```
ansible_user       : "{{ lookup('keepass', 'path/to/entry', 'username') }}"
ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('keepass', 'path/to/entry', 'password') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but it seems your use case is primarily covered by [keepass-inventory](https://github.com/kubanczyk/keepass-inventory/). And it doesn't require any playbook "magic". Disclaimer: I contribute to this non-profit.

```
export KDB_PATH=example.kdbx
export KDB_PASS=example

ansible all --list-hosts -i keepass-inventory.py
```